# Docker command `npm run` behaves different in GitLab and in local machine

Tags: node.js, npm, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, npm-scripts

I built the follow Docker container

```
FROM node:20-alpine as ember
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json /usr/app/
RUN apk fix && \
    apk --no-cache --update add git && \
    npm clean-install
```

and uploaded to a registery.

`npm run built` works as expected from `docker compose up` with `compose.yaml` as

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: my-docker-image
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /usr/app
    command: npm run build
```

When I try to run `npm run build` from GitLab CI, I get the error `sh: ember: not found`. The GitLab CI task/job is

```
npm-run:
  image: my-docker-image
  script:
    - npm run build
```

Why npm is not working in GitLab CI?

Comment: Post your `package.json` content.

Comment: `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in https://gist.github.com/rgaiacs/20627714cb444a3e1fc62691ab2fd48c

Answer (score 0):

GitLab CI overwrite Docker's `WORKDIR` to `/builds/username/repository`. Because of this, the current directory (`/builds/username/repository`) did **not** have the `node_modules` as it was installed in `/usr/app/` and `npm run built` fails.

In the local machine, the development `node_modules` also overwrite the `node_modules` in the Docker container. Because of this, `npm run built` runs as expected.

Change my GitLab CI configuration to

```
npm-run:
  image: my-docker-image
  script:
    - ln -s ../../../usr/app/node_modules node_modules
    - npm run build
```

resolved the problem.

Additional note: Change my GitLab CI configuration to

```
npm-run:
  image: my-docker-image
  script:
    - npm run --prefix ../../../usr/app build
```

did **not** resolved the problem because `--prefix ../../../usr/app` is equivalent to `cd ../../../usr/app` and `npm` couldn't find my project files.